Getting value of a non-volatile register in language-specific exception handler
What is the expected/cleanest way of getting the value of a non-volatile register in a language-specific exception handler in x64 (see MSDN)?
It seems that such a handler gets two "CONTEXT"-objects, which theoretically contain the values of the registers. However, the "contextRecord" parameter is the value of the register at the point the exception is raised. And the "DispatcherContext->Context" member seems to contain the value of the register after the current function is unwound. I've made some runnable code to showcase this issue:
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <exception>
#include <cassert>

/// <summary>
/// UNWIND INFO
/// </summary>

struct UNWIND_INFO
{
    uint8_t version : 3;
    uint8_t flags : 5;
    uint8_t prologSize;
    uint8_t unwindCount;
    uint8_t frameRegister : 4;
    uint8_t frameOffset : 4;
};

static_assert(sizeof(UNWIND_INFO) == 4);

struct UNWIND_CODE
{
    uint8_t offset;
    uint8_t opCode : 4;
    uint8_t opInfo : 4;
};

static_assert(sizeof(UNWIND_CODE) == 2);

enum class UNWIND_OP_CODES : uint8_t
{
    UWOP_PUSH_NONVOL = 0,
    UWOP_ALLOC_LARGE,
    UWOP_ALLOC_SMALL,
    UWOP_SET_FPREG,
    UWOP_SAVE_NONVOL,
    UWOP_SAVE_NONVOL_FAR,
    UWOP_SAVE_XMM128,
    UWOP_SAVE_XMM128_FAR,
    UWOP_PUSH_MACHFRAME
};

/// <summary>
/// CODE GEN/EXECUTION
/// </summary>

// toggle this to test working vs non-working variants

static constexpr uint8_t RDI_VALUE = 123;

static uint64_t s_oldRDI = -1;

[[noreturn]] void throwException(uint64_t oldRDI)
{
    s_oldRDI = oldRDI;

    throw std::exception();
}

EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION handleException(PEXCEPTION_RECORD exceptionRecord, ULONG64 establisherFrame, PCONTEXT contextRecord, PDISPATCHER_CONTEXT dispatcherContext)
{
    assert(dispatcherContext->ContextRecord->Rdi == s_oldRDI);
    assert(dispatcherContext->ContextRecord->Rdi == RDI_VALUE);

    return EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION::ExceptionContinueSearch;
}

constexpr uint8_t callCode[] =
{
    // push        rdi
    0x57,
    // sub         rsp,20h
    0x48, 0x83, 0xEC, 0x20,
    // mov         rcx,rdi
    0x48, 0x89, 0xF9,
    // mov          rdi,123
    0x48, 0xC7, 0xC7, RDI_VALUE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    // call qword ptr[rip+11]
    0xFF, 0x15, 0x0B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    // movaps     xmm6,xmmword ptr [rsp+20h]
    0x0F, 0x28, 0x74, 0x24, 0x20,
    // add      rsp,20h
    0x48, 0x83, 0xC4, 0x20,
    // pop      rdi
    0x5F,
    // ret
    0xC3
};

constexpr uint8_t exceptionHandlerCode[] =
{
    // jmp qword ptr[rip+0]
    0xFF, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};

static constexpr auto UNWIND_OFFSET = 4096;
static constexpr auto EXCEPTION_HANDLER_OFFSET = sizeof(callCode) + sizeof(void*);

RUNTIME_FUNCTION funcTable[] =
{
    {
        .BeginAddress = 0,
        .EndAddress = sizeof(callCode),
        .UnwindInfoAddress = UNWIND_OFFSET
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto pCode = (uint8_t*)VirtualAlloc(nullptr, 4096 * 2, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

    // setup function-code
    {
        memcpy(pCode, callCode, sizeof(callCode));
        // place cpp-function address in table
        new (pCode + sizeof(callCode)) const void* (&throwException);
    }

    // setup exception-hanlder code
    {
        auto* pExceptionHandler = pCode + EXCEPTION_HANDLER_OFFSET;
        memcpy(pExceptionHandler, exceptionHandlerCode, sizeof(exceptionHandlerCode));
        new (pExceptionHandler + sizeof(exceptionHandlerCode)) const void* (&handleException);
    }

    // allow execution
    DWORD oldProtect;
    VirtualProtect(pCode, 4096, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);

    // setup runtime-function table
    {
        auto* pUnwindInfoStart = pCode + UNWIND_OFFSET;

        const auto writeUnwindData = [&]<typename T>(T data)
        {
            static constexpr auto SIZE = uint32_t(sizeof(data));

            auto* pUnwindTarget = pUnwindInfoStart;
            pUnwindInfoStart += SIZE;

            new (pUnwindTarget) T(data);
        };

        writeUnwindData(UNWIND_INFO
        {
            .version = 1,
            .flags = UNW_FLAG_EHANDLER,
            .prologSize = 5,
            .unwindCount = 2,
            .frameRegister = 0,
            .frameOffset = 0,
        });

        const auto writeUnwindCode = [&](uint8_t prologOffset, UNWIND_OP_CODES opCode, uint8_t info)
        {
            writeUnwindData(UNWIND_CODE{ prologOffset, uint8_t(opCode), info });
        };

        writeUnwindCode(5, UNWIND_OP_CODES::UWOP_ALLOC_SMALL, 3);
        writeUnwindCode(1, UNWIND_OP_CODES::UWOP_PUSH_NONVOL, 7);
        // exception handler relative address
        writeUnwindData(ULONG(EXCEPTION_HANDLER_OFFSET));

        if (RtlAddFunctionTable(funcTable, 1, DWORD64(pCode)) == FALSE)
            return -1;

        DWORD64 module;
        auto* pFunc = RtlLookupFunctionEntry(DWORD64(pCode), &module, nullptr);
        assert(pFunc == funcTable);
    }

    using Func = void(*)();
    auto pFunc = Func(pCode);

    try
    {
        pFunc();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

This showcases my use-case (a custom asm compiler targeting x64), the involved processes, as well as the issue. The compiled function sets "RDI" to a value, and the exception-handler would need to access the value of RDI during that function-call. However, "dispatcherContext->ContextRecord->Rdi" seems to contain the value of RDI before my call - I store that value in a global and compare them - expected would be for the first assertion to be triggered, but in reality it's the second one.
Is there anything wrong in my setup, or are you expected to get the register-values of the function that this exception-handler belongs to from somewhere else? I found a work-around, in the way of manually RtlVirtualUnwind-ing from the top of the current callstack, but this is both awkward as well as slow and somewhat unsafe:
CONTEXT context;
RtlCaptureContext(&context);

while (context.Rip)
{
    DWORD64 imgbase;
    const auto func = RtlLookupFunctionEntry((DWORD64)context.Rip, &imgbase, dispatcherContext->HistoryTable);

    const auto begin = imgbase + func->BeginAddress;
    const auto end = imgbase + func->EndAddress;

    if (dispatcherContext->ControlPc >= begin && dispatcherContext->ControlPc <= end)
    {
        // context now contains the correct values
        assert(context.Rdi == RDI_VALUE);

        break;
    }

    PVOID handlerdata;
    ULONG64 establisherFramePointer;

    RtlVirtualUnwind(UNW_FLAG_NHANDLER, imgbase, (DWORD64)context.Rip, func, &context, &handlerdata, &establisherFramePointer, nullptr);
}

Is there a better solution?
